# In nushell how can I combine where clauses

Tags: nushell

I have this [nushell](https://www.nushell.sh/) query:

```sh
open ./s3_actions.csv | where actions !~ 'Acl' | where actions !~ 'Cors' | where actions !~ 'Job' | where actions !~ 'Retention' | where actions !~ 'Legal' | where actions !~ 'Payment' | where actions !~ 'Policy' | where actions !~ 'Configuration' | where actions !~ 'Replicate' | where actions !~ 'AccessPoint'
```

Is there a way I could combine all the `where actions !~ ...` clauses into one big list ?

The closest I got was [here](https://www.nushell.sh/book/variables_and_subexpressions.html#short-hand-subexpressions-row-conditions) but I don't know how to do nested loops, both would have the same `$it` variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't provide any sample data to validate against, but I assumed something like:

```
actions,element,node,something
Acl Forward Bar Baz,52206,19075,71281
Legal Stack,31210,21366,52576
Configuration Help Doc,13684,65142,78826
Help Doc,48488,44794,93282
Baz Bar Foo,13140,60057,73197
Foo Baz Bar,62892,63836,126728
,64022,54909,118930
Abc,50240,16109,66348
Def Bar Foo,18680,17847,36526
Acl Bar Vegas,55553,22953,78506
Taco Hamburger Sushi,30311,42345,72656
```

It's possible there's another way for your particular data source, but the following line (split to multiple lines for improved readability) returns the same results as the multiple `where` clauses in your question:

```
open ./s3_actions.csv | where {|it| 
    (["Acl", "Cors", "Job", "Retention", "Legal", "Payment", "Policy", "Configuration", "Replicate", "AccessPoint"] | 
    reduce -f true { |action,acc|
        ($it.actions !~ $action) && $acc
    })
}
```

*Explanation:*

Ultimately, what you are asking for is a way to "reduce" a "list of where actions" down to a single value, `true` or `false`.  Look to the `reduce` command for that.

In this particular case:

- `where` is run for each record returned from `s3_actions.csv`
- For each record, `reduce` is then run for each action in the list.  It starts with the accumulator (`acc`) set to `true`, but if *any* of the tests returns `false`, it will become false when the two are `&&` (and)'ed.

And yes, because there are two blocks here (for `where` *and* `reduce`), you'll need to use a different name for the arguments for each.

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably just use the `&&` or `and` operator like  `... | where x == y && a == b && z == d`

Comment: That was my first answer (since deleted), but then I reread the question and it seemed to be more about how to process the actual actions as a "list", but perhaps I'm reading it too literally.